# Values from XSL parameters are showing up as undefined in GA4 select_item event

Tags: jquery, xslt, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I'm working on converting our Universal Analytics dataLayer into the GA4 format, and as part of this I need to create events to collect data that would previously have been passively sent on pageload with the pageview tag.

The add_to_cart function works fine, so I thought it would be straightforward to add a select_item function that operates in the same way, but instead all the attributes are returning undefined.

```
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Products/Product" mode="dataLayer"></xsl:apply-templates>

<script>
                window.onload = function() {
                     addAttributes();
                     $("input.SelectItemButton").click(selectItem);
                }

                

                function addAttributes() {
                     var selButton = document.getElementsByClassName("SelectItemButton");
     
                     for <![CDATA[(var i=0; i<selButton.length; i++)]]> {
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-name", $('input:hidden[name=selName]').val());
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-id", $('input:hidden[name=selId]').val());
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-brand", $('input:hidden[name=selBrand]').val());
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-category", $('input:hidden[name=selCategory]').val());
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-variant", $('input:hidden[name=selVariant]').val());
                          selButton[i].setAttribute("data-finish", $('input:hidden[name=selFinish]').val());
                          }
                    }


                function selectItem() {
                    dataLayer.push({
                        event: "select_item",
                        ecommerce: {
                            item_list_id: "related_products",
                            item_list_name: "Related products",
                            items: [
                            {
                              item_id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                              item_name: $(this).attr('data-name'),
                              index: 0,
                              item_brand: $(this).attr('data-brand'),
                              item_category: $(this).attr('data-category'),
                              item_category2: $(this).attr('data-finish'),
                              item_list_id: "related_products",
                              item_list_name: "Related Products",
                              item_variant: $(this).attr('data-variant'),
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
                }

            </script>
```

and then further down in the xml package is the referenced xsl template:

```
           <xsl:template match="Product" mode="dataLayer">
                <xsl:param name="selName"><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="selId"><xsl:value-of select="ProductID" /></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="selBrand"><xsl:value-of select="MaterialList" /></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="selCategory"><xsl:value-of select="ShapeList" /></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="selVariant"><xsl:value-of select="GradeList" /></xsl:param>
                <xsl:param name="selFinish"><xsl:value-of select="Finish" /></xsl:param>

                $(document).ready(function() {
                <input type="hidden" name="selName" value="{$selName}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selId" value="{$selId}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selBrand" value="{$selBrand}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selCategory" value="{$selCategory}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selVariant" value="{$selVariant}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="selFinish" value="{$selFinish}" />
                });
            </xsl:template>
```

I suspect that the problem might be that something's not happening in the right order, but when I've tried to move the xsl template around to different places it breaks the whole page. I know the addAttributes() function runs because it does add the attributes - it just doesn't assign them values. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I suspect it's not relevant, but with `<xsl:param name="selName"><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></xsl:param>` you are creating a result tree fragment, which you then reduce to a string when you write `value="{$selName}"/>`. That's totally unnecessary, you should use the much simpler `<xsl:param name="selName" select="Name" />`

Comment: I don't understand your logic, but I suspect you are getting confused between what happens at during XSLT processing (when the HTML is generated) and what happens subsequently (when the HTML is loaded and becomes interactive).

Comment: The use of `{$selName}` within a text in `<xsl:template>` does _not_ output the value of `$selName`, it outputs `{$selName}` literally.

Comment: @MichaelKay you're not wrong. I agree my code is a logical mess. Decided to start over - I'll post the new version below, which does work as far as getting the correct values from the database. The tag still doesn't seem to fire, but that's a separate issue!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was to start over and simplify things...a lot.

```
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input.SelectItemButton").click(selectItem);
    });
    function selectItem() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });
        dataLayer.push(<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Categories/Category" mode="dataLayer"></xsl:apply-templates>);
                    }
</script>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="Category" mode="dataLayer">
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">{
  event: "select_item",
  ecommerce: {
    item_list_id: "related_products",
    item_list_name: "Related products",
    items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: 'Name',
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: '<xsl:value-of select="MaterialList" />',
      item_category: '<xsl:value-of select="ShapeList" />',
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: '<xsl:value-of select="GradeList" />',
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 10.01,
      quantity: 3
    }
    ]
  }
}
</xsl:if></xsl:template>
```

It still needs some work and a bunch of things filled in, but I think it's heading in a better direction now. Thanks to the commenters for their feedback that sent me in a better direction!